# CoreMediaErrorDomain tag double value with HLS media on iOs?

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am playing a HLS url on iOs Native player and getting the following error

```
#Fields: date time uri cs-guid s-ip status domain comment cs-iftype

    2022/11/23 19:50:19.019 media.m3u8 - - -12642 "CoreMediaErrorDomain" "tag double value: Illegal decimal conversion" -

    2022/11/23 19:50:19.019 media.m3u8 911BEC21-F9B9-46F7-88D4-3FC95CDE9490 - -12642 "CoreMediaErrorDomain" "Playlist parse error" -

    2022/11/23 19:50:19.019 media.m3u8 911BEC21-F9B9-46F7-88D4-3FC95CDE9490 - -12642 "CoreMediaErrorDomain" "The operation couldn’t be completed. (CoreMediaErrorDomain error -12642 - playlist parse error.)" wifi-infra
```

This is the m3u8 playlist

```
#EXTM3U
    #EXT-X-VERSION:3
    #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:7
    #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:9
    #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0
    #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-11-23T14:20:29.103Z
    #EXTINF:6.006,
    http://media/720_9183201.ts
    #EXTINF:6.006,
    http://media/720_9183202.ts
    #EXTINF:6.006,
    http://media/720_9183203.ts
    #EXTINF:6.006,
    http://media/720_9183204.ts
    #EXTINF:6.006,
    http://media/720_9183205.ts
    #EXTINF:6.006,
    http://media/720_9183206.ts
    #EXTINF:0.334,
    http://media/720_9183207.ts
    #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
    #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2022-11-23T14:21:05.473Z
    #EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="d7518dca-f9a8-4a36-9d56-b89658798541",START-DATE="2022-11-23T14:21:05.473Z",PLANNED-DURATION=37.0,X-AD-POD-SIZE=1,X-AD-VAST=http://vast/vast.xml
    #EXT-X-DATERANGE:ID="dfbc3202-1a78-4ce6-8bc8-2d7669b3ec07",START-DATE="2022-11-23T14:21:05.473Z",PLANNED-DURATION=37.0,X-AD-ID="104314"
    #EXTINF:6.0,
    https://ad/720_720p_0000.ts
```

Is there something wrong with the manifest